# How to make less +F follow symbolic link if link changes

Tags: logs, symlink, less

When you tail a file that is a symbolic link you can make *tail* follow the link if it changes with *tail -F*.

Is there someone that have a solution to make less behave the same way if you're opening a symbolic link in less and press `F`and while following the symbolink link it is changed to point to another file?

Edit: I'm aware of launching less with `+F` but often wante to launch less without `+F` since to search for something and later on maybe start tailing the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [`less`](https://manpages.debian.org/less/less#follow-name) manpage:

> `--follow-name`
>
> Normally, if the input file is renamed while an F command is
> executing, less will continue to display the contents of the original
> file despite its name change. If `--follow-name` is specified, during an
> `F` command *less* will periodically attempt to reopen the file by name.
> If the reopen succeeds and the file is a different file from the
> original (which means that a new file has been created with the same
> name as the original (now renamed) file), less will display the
> contents of that new file.

So depending on use case one can use `less --follow-name` (and type an uppercase `F` when the need arises) or use `less --follow-name +F` (to have the `F` behavior immediately).

This [option](https://manpages.debian.org/less/less.1#OPTIONS) could also be put for example in the [`LESS` environment variable](https://manpages.debian.org/less/less.1#LESS) to avoid having to type it each time.

---

By the way `--follow-name` is not specifically about symbolic links, but it applies to a replaced symbolic link pointing to a different file.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't see or understand at first what follow-name actually did. I should have stated in my question that I didn't wanted to launch less with `+F` since I often want to search for something in the file first and then maybe start tailing the log but adding `--follow-name` as always being added solves that case as it seems. Thank you!

Comment: Modified answer accordingly.

Comment: Great note about LESS environment variable, thanks!